"Centroid" induced by metric
A metric $d(x,y)$ on a vector space $V$ can be used to induce the definition of a centroid of a points set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ with respect to this metric as a (not necessarily unique) point $c$ that minimizes
$$c = \sum_{i=1}^n d(c,x_i)$$
A typical example is the statistical mean (aka center of mass) as the "centroid" with respect to the Euclidean metric.
Is there an established name for this "centroid"? And is there some theory under what conditions upon the metric the centroid is unique?
Edit: Just learned that the "centroid" that minimizes the sum of squared distances is called a Fréchet Mean. It is sometimes also called barycenter, although this term seems to be primarily used in combination with the $W_2$ Wasserstein distance.

You don't really need $d$ to be a metric: you could formulate the same question for any function $d:V\times V\to\mathbb R.$  An examination of standard applications, such as is encountered in optimal siting of distribution centers within a transportation network, ought to convince you there is no general set of conditions to guarantee unique solutions: even when $d$ looks badly behaved, $c$ can still be unique.

You may be interested in some of the Gneiting papers that talk about what functionals are elicited by minimizing particular loss functions. Our Stephan Kolassa has posted some citations.

@Dave Can you please provide some links to the relevant answers? I have searched for the combination "Kolassa" and "Gneiting", but only found stuff about financtial forecasting methods.

These might be useful. @cdalitz

@whuber That's a good point. Actually my example with the center of mass does not minimize the Euclidean distance, but the squared Euclidean distance, which is not even a metric. I have just learned that a point that minimizes the sum of squared distances is called a Fréchet Mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean.
